# C#: duplicate opened form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a single button to open another form in my main form.
My issue is if I click again the same button it open **another** form again.

I want that the button if I click again **do not** open another form but instead locate the opened form to center or original start position. Without clearing the text written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look in [`Application.OpenForms`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx) and check if there is an open instance of your second form, show it, else create an instance of your second form and show it:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var f = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (f == null)
    {
        f = new Form2();
        f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        f.Show();
    }
    f.Activate();
}
```

Comment: sir i cannot call the **CenterToScreen** function

Comment: @officepuppy Corrected, Thanks. It's a protected method and you cannot use it for other forms, also for your current form you should not use it as mentioned in documentations.

Comment: I Also edited your question to remove the answer from it. It makes the question confusing for future readers.

Comment: You don't need your new posted question, this post seems to answer your question. Do you have any other question about it?

Comment: Sir i've entered the **FormStartPosition.CenterScreen** as you suggested still the form start at the upper left corner. Is it because this is a child form?

Comment: This post answers your current question. I read your new question. It's about showing the form in the panel. I'll answer your new question there. Now you can accept and vote for this answer.